# ShapeRenderer Transformations Interfering with Mesh Transformations in LibGDX

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, transformation, mesh

I'm working on a game with a lot of rotational transformations and I'm running into a problem with something that seems pretty simple - I assume I'm doing something wrong.

I draw a triangle with a ShapeRenderer like so:

```
shapeRend.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRend.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
shapeRend.identity();
shapeRend.translate(xx, yy, 0);
shapeRend.rotate(0, 0, 1, angle);
shapeRend.triangle(-.08f, -.08f, .08f, -.08f, 0, +.08f);
shapeRend.end();
shapeRend.identity();
```

Which works all fine and dandy, but I have some meshes that I draw somewhere else. For any transformations on this triangle (and I assume all shaperenderers) that occur and then get *drawn*, these transformations then affect all meshes. This is a real pain.

As transformations on meshes are handled by actually altering the vertices (what I could see in the source), I think something else is at play where the OpenGL transformations are not being reset after the ShapeRenderer is transformed? It's very frustrating and it does seem like a glitch but it would be a pretty big one seeing as I can't see it not being spotted until now. Any suggestions?

I'm running on the "latest" nightly build of LibGDX using OpenGL ES 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenGL ES 1.x, the `ShapeRenderer` uses an [`ImmediateModeRenderer10`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ImmediateModeRenderer10.java) (see the [`ShapeRenderer` constructor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.java#L111)).  The `ShapeRenderer` does track the rotations in its own `Matrix4` (the "transform" field), but when [`begin(Matrix4, int)`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ImmediateModeRenderer10.java#L93) is invoked on the underlying renderer, the combined camera+transformation matrix is passed down and its gets stored into **global** OpenGL state (the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix specifically).

The `ShapeRenderer` does not "push" or "pop" the global matrix state, so either you can do this yourself around the shapeRend calls (see http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/pop_and_push_matrices.html) to save/restore your matrices or you can simply reset the `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` matrices before you render your mesh.  The second approach would be more in line with how most of Libgdx works (each of the various renderers will setup the state it depends upon at `begin()` and not assume anything in the global state survives).

Alternatively, you could switch to OpenGL ES 2.0, which does not have any global matrix state (all the transforms are by a shader-private "uniform", see [`ImmeidateModeRenderer20.end()`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ImmediateModeRenderer20.java#L129)).

Comment: Switching to OpenGL ES 2.0 seemed to be the best solution, even if that presented troubles of its own. I thought I may have been forced to later anyway as shaders can be really useful, so I may as well do that now. On top of that, I couldn't seem to get pushing and popping matrices working quickly.